# Postgres Query to know the db is up and running

Tags: java, database, hibernate

**(EDITED)**
I am using the following code to check if my Postgres db is up and running. However if the machine running the db is slow (Not enough RAM for example) it sometimes pass but when i tried to get some real data from the db (a few millisec after) i fail. I guess because not all tables were loaded.
Here is my code:

```
public static boolean testDBConnection(boolean refreshFactory) throws Exception
    Session session = null;
    try {
        if(refreshFactory){
            ConnectionUtil.refreshSessionFactory();
        }
        session = ConnectionUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String sql = "select 1";
        session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();

        return true;
    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        String error = "Failed to connect db."; 
        throw ExceptionFactory.create(error);
    }
    finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a better way then "select 1"?

Thanks

Comment: Don't get it. Postgres is very powerful, what it mean very slow db? Or maybe you mean when the running time is too long, it fail.

Comment: I mean that the machine running postgres is very slow (not enough RAM for example)